# How to stop the main process while the spawned threads finish execution

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's my code

```
public class Main {

private static class GetData implements Runnable{

    private List list;
    private SqlQuery query;
    GetData(SqlQuery<String> param){
        this.query=param;
    }

    public void run(){


        list = query.execute();

    }

}


public static void main(String[] args){

    ApplicationContext context = new      ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("database.xml");
    SqlQuery<String> parameter =  (SqlQuery<String>) context.getBean("BEAN_NAME");

    System.out.println("hello");


    new Thread(new Inner(parameter)).start();


   for(each element in list of inner class){

       System.out.println(element.id);
   }

}

}
```

Well my question is after i get the query from xml file, it executes but it doesnt print anything? Why?

Also, how do i ensure that after all my threads have finished execution, only then my main program moves ahead in execution, given i make another thread and run it to create another list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
new Thread(new Inner(parameter)).start();
```

to

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Inner(parameter));
t.start();
```

and put   `t.join();` **after** your for loop.

**EDIT**:
      For 5 or any number of threads say n

Create an array of threads like this

```
Thread[] tArray = new Thread[n];

for (int j = 0; j < tArray .length; j++) {

//your code to start the thread goes here

}
```

Once you have started them all, loop through them again **at the end of the main** function to join each of them to main thread.

```
for (int j = 0; j < tarray .length; j++) {

tArray.join()

}
```

Comment: say i have to create 5 threads and after all of them have finished execution i want to do sysout on the list populated by them?

Can you edit your answer accordingly? thanks.

Comment: I tried after t.join, create new Thread t2 and t2.start and t2.join, but i guess this will halt the construction of t2 till after t1 has finished.

Comment: @Kraken for your use case, using the java.util.concurrent package will make your life easier than dealing with threads directly.

Comment: @Kraken put the `join()` at the end of the main function where the `main()` is about the exit.

Comment: @Santosh and what shall it be? t1.join, t2.join, t3.join..... and so on, given i have multiple threads?

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your suggestion. A array of thread should help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **join** method of the thread you want to wait. [Thread.join() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

how it works :

The thread (lets call him A) that join another thread (called B) will stop it execution until the joined thread (B) finish and returns.

**EDIT** :
In fact, unless your Thread is in Daemon mode, your program won't exit. 
The JVM automatically joins all running non daemon thread before exiting

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one Thread and want main program waits its execution completed. You do not need to use Thread mechanism. Instead, you can add a method in main program in substance to Thread.run().
Otherwise if you want to use multiple thread you can use Thread.join method so that all other threads wait at that line until all thread execution are completed.
I also advice you to investifate countdownlatch mechanism. It can give you ready mechanism not to involve in Join/wait operations manually.

Comment: if i do Thread.join() once i have created a couple of threads it says `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method join() from the type Thread`.

Comment: You cannot directly invoke Thread.join() method. It was a representation that I want to show. You could decleare Thread instanaces such as Thread t1 = new Thread()...., Thread t2 = new Thread()..... Then invoke t1.join() and t2.join(). It will make main program wait all threads until each of them completed its execution.

Answer (score 0):

`new Thread(runnable).start();` executes the provided runnable asynchronously and continues the execution to the next line, so the loop executes before anything has been added to the list.

So if you want to execute the loop after the thread has finished, you will have to wait for it. The easiest way is to run the Runnable: `new Inner(parameter).run();`.

Now that defeats the purpose of parallel execution.

Assuming you have more than one runnable, you could use an ExecutorService (instead of using the low-level Thread API, which is more complicated to use and error-prone) to run the various tasks in parallel and collect the results when they are all completed:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
executor.submit(runnable1); //first task
executor.submit(runnable2); //second task

executor.shutdown(); //stop accepting new tasks
executor.awaiTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //wait until both tasks finish

//now you can use the results of your tasks.
```

Finally, note that if you use threads, you will be sharing the list in your runnable across threads (the worker thread and the main thread) and you will need to use a thread safe structure to make that possible - for example, by using a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html):

```
list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(query.execute());
```